# Segmentation fault when accessing a structure

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, structure

The program works all the way up until it checks for the name the user enters. When you enter the name you wish to search for in the array of structures that have been imported from a file full of customer info) it comes back segmentation fault core dumped. This puzzles me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct AccountsDataBase{

        char name[50];
        string email;
        long int phone;
        string address;
};


#define MAX 80

AccountsDataBase * account = new AccountsDataBase[MAX];


void readIn(ifstream& file){
        int i=0;
        while(!file.eof()){
                file >> account[i].name >> account[i].email >> account[i].phone >> account[i].address;
        }
}

void getAccount(){

        char userPick[50];
        char streamName[50];

        cout << " What account will we  be using? " << endl;

        cin.getline(streamName, 50);

        for(int i=0; strcmp(account[i].name, streamName)!=0; i++){
                if( strcmp(account[i].name, streamName)==0){
                        cout << "\n\n FOUND IT!! \n\n";
                        cout << account[i].name << "\n" << account[i].email << "\n" << account[i].phone << "\n" << account[i].address << endl;
                }
        }
}

int main(){
        ifstream file;
        file.open("2.dat"); //opens data account records text
        readIn(file);
        getAccount();
        delete account;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger first?

Comment: @colin No need for line #'s unless your error indicates a specific lines

Comment: @Colin Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Comment: @OldProgrammer i am using vim editor and is giving me an entire memory map along with a statement saying invalid pointer but as a programmer of only one year i have not the slightest idea of how to retrace this hex # back to my source code.

Comment: I would suggest to spend some time learning debugging skills.  It will save you lots of headaches.

Comment: any sites recommended? @OldProgrammer

Comment: and @sashoalm you have not a single bit of ownership of this site. This site doesnt sale shares you have no say so for any occurrence on this site you might think your entitled to something do to your time put in but you simply are not. This site is about public programmers and what they want. There is no dictation that will take place on here.

Comment: @ColinRickels What does that have to do with anything? The link I gave you is community consensus. There are policies against the so called [help vampires](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) - people who use this site for free debugging of their code, who provide no value for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop keeps reading everything into the initial element of the array:

```
while(!file.eof()){
    file >> account[i].name >> account[i].email >> account[i].phone >> account[i].address;
}
```

because the value of `i` is never incremented. You can convert this to a `for` loop, like this:

```
for (count = 0 ; count < MAX && !file.eof() ; count++) {
    file >> account[count].name >> account[count].email >> account[count].phone >> account[count].address;
}
```

Note that I changed `i` to `count`:

```
AccountsDataBase * account = new AccountsDataBase[MAX];
int count = 0;
```

This will help you solve another problem - determining when the array ends in the `getAccount` function. Currently, you assume that the record is always there, so the outer loop keeps going on. Now that you have `count`, you could change the loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < count && strcmp(account[i].name, streamName)!=0; i++){
    if( strcmp(account[i].name, streamName)==0){
        cout << "\n\n FOUND IT!! \n\n";
        cout << account[i].name << "\n" << account[i].email << "\n" << account[i].phone << "\n" << account[i].address << endl;
        break;
    }
}
if (i == count) {
    cout << "Not found." << endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you the first answer was a stupid mistake on my part. The second part is beyond my knowledge, wouldnt know how to fix that problem, however it its giving an entire new breed of segmentation fault now that i updated the loop and is printing an entire memory map

Comment: @ColinRickels Take a look at the edit, it should make it easier for you to spot the new segfault.